# JS not working on echoed PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

So I have a form that is submitted via an Ajax POST request.  After the send button is clicked, the form is removed and a processing graphic is put in its place.  The form data is sent to my PHP script, validated, and a thank you message returns to replace the processing graphic if everything checks out.  But if there is a validation error, I have a copy of the entire form echoed back to the div where the original form was at showing where the errors are in the form.  This all works fine except when the copy of the form is echoed back, the JS for the form doesn't work?  Neither the JS for the send button or for my focus/blur functions on the inputs.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: JS actions probably need rebinding

Comment: Dont remove the form, just hide it until you'll get AJAX response. If there is no error - only then remove the form (if its really needed of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove the form from the DOM, the events are cancelled as well. You can have a function that sets these events and call it when there are errors in the response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'd actually already had the same idea as you did and tried it but it didn't work the first time.  After reading your question I realized I probably didn't refresh the browser after saving the changes to my code.  I tried the idea again, refreshed the browser and now it works great...  Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to just hide your form and display the processing graphic instead of removing the form ? And when you have an error, hide the graphic and display the form again.
With this solution, error handling will be a little more difficult, but you will not have your form at 2 places in your project !

Comment: No, I didn't try hiding it.  Good idea though.  I didn't think about doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert HTML mixed Javascript into some node, eg a div, it isn't the same as serving it the first time as part of the whole document. It isn't considered a script when inserted as innerHTML or some textnode.

You have a few options:

** Switch visibility and encode the errorresponse (in JSON for example)

Create 2 divs, one holding the form, the other the PROCESSING image.

Switch display to none for the form when processing, and the image to block.

When you have processed the form and you have an error, encode it somehow (JSON, eg) and send that back, and let an EXISTING script on the page interpret the response.

You can for example create some structure that holds each formelementname, and the error associated with it, so you can easily highlight them in your form if you create an empty span next to each formelement where you can display the error.

When the answer arrives from the server, you can display the form again, and display:none the PROCESSING div.

** Interpret your response (WITH JAVASCRIPT)

This is more difficult, but also more elegant. 
I once needed this (Javascript that returned from an XHR request), and Randy Webb helped me out with a smart approach.

It is too much to explain here. 
Read this thread for a more detailed approach, and links to the script of Randy:

http://tinyurl.com/6pakdu

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'mypage.html',
  success: function(){
    alert('success');
    **<ADD YOUR CUSTOM CODE AFTER AJAX SUCCESS - JS CODE>**
  },
  error: function(){ 
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also ref.
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

```
 $.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
   },
   complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
   }
   // ......
 });
```